# Typescript - dynamic array of promises with different return values

Tags: arrays, typescript, types, promise, promise.all

Can anyone help me solve what's wrong with this code?
I can't find the right type to put in that `Promise.all` call at the bottom.
it tried also `Promise.all<Services[], PullRequests[]>(ops)` but `PullRequests[]` can't be optional...

```js
function wait<Twait>(time: number, response: Twait): Promise<Twait> {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(response), time))
}

interface Service {
    name: string;
    id: number;
}

async function getServices(): Promise<Service[]>  {
    const response = await wait(400, { "id": 200 });
    return [{ name: "service", id: response.id }]
}


interface PullRequest {
    prType: string;
    githubId: number;
}

async function getPrs(): Promise<PullRequest[]>  {
    const response = await wait(400, { "githubId": 200 });
    return [{ prType: "foo", githubId: response.githubId }]
}


async function main(): Promise<void> {

    const ops: [ PromiseLike<Service[]>, PromiseLike<PullRequest[]>? ] = [getServices()]

    if (Math.random() > 0.5) { // <== this is random on purpose.
        ops.push(getPrs())
    }
    
    
    const [ services, prs ] = await Promise.all(ops) // This throws a ts compile error (attached below)
    console.log("services:")
    console.log(services)
    console.log("prs:")
    console.log(prs)    
}
```

```
No overload matches this call. The last overload gave the following error.
 Argument of type '[PromiseLike<Service[]>, (PromiseLike<PullRequest[]> | undefined)?]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<Service[] | PromiseLike<Service[] | undefined> | undefined>'. 
The types returned by '[Symbol.iterator]().next(...)' are incompatible between these types. 
Type 'IteratorResult<PromiseLike<Service[]> | PromiseLike<PullRequest[]> | undefined, any>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<Service[] | PromiseLike<Service[] | undefined> | undefined, any>'. 
Type 'IteratorYieldResult<PromiseLike<Service[]> | PromiseLike<PullRequest[]> | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<Service[] | PromiseLike<Service[] | undefined> | undefined, any>'. 
Type 'IteratorYieldResult<PromiseLike<Service[]> | PromiseLike<PullRequest[]> | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorYieldResult<Service[] | PromiseLike<Service[] | undefined> | undefined>'. 
Type 'PromiseLike<Service[]> | PromiseLike<PullRequest[]> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Service[] | PromiseLike<Service[] | undefined> | undefined'. 
Type 'PromiseLike<PullRequest[]>' is not assignable to type 'Service[] | PromiseLike<Service[] | undefined> | undefined'. 
Type 'PromiseLike<PullRequest[]>' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike<Service[] | undefined>'. 
Type 'PullRequest[]' is not assignable to type 'Service[]'. 
Type 'PullRequest' is missing the following properties from type 'Service': name, id
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a known issue in TS library definitions, according to [microsoft/TypeScript#28427](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28427). Currently the library hardcodes a bunch of specific tuple types which do not include optional elements.  There has been some effort taken to fix this, but apparently `PromiseLike` types and how they interact with `await` are complicated enough that none of the pull requests fixing this have been accepted yet. [A comment in microsoft/TypeScript#39788](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39788#issuecomment-665223322) explains that switching this might break existing real world code that depends on the current definitions.

Until and unless this gets addressed upstream, you could use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#introduction) to add your own signature for `Promise.all()` that just [maps](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) the promise unwrapping over the elements of the passed-in array-or-tuple:

```
interface PromiseConstructor {
  all<T extends readonly any[]>(
    values: { [K in keyof T]: T[K] | PromiseLike<T[K]> }
  ): Promise<T>;
}
```

And you can test that it does what you want:

```
const promiseAllOps = Promise.all(ops); // no error now  
// const promiseAllOps: Promise<[Service[], (PullRequest[] | undefined)?]>
const awaitPromiseAllOps = await promiseAllOps;
// const awaitPromiseAllOps: [Service[], (PullRequest[] | undefined)?]
const [services, prs] = awaitPromiseAllOps;
services; // Service[]
prs; // PullRequest[] | undefined
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/PTAEFsFMCcHNNASwHagC4AtEGcCwAoFNGAMwEMBjBABWgHtwdIBhO5bNaAVwrTulABvAqFBkANuIA8AFVCQAHsWQATbKGiQyKtuICeY5HoDaAXQB8AChGjQANwldI2AFxDQxgNJJUAa0h6dCSgMqZuMl6moAA+oLQMTAAyiP6ykeagAL42AJRu8YzYkLLmANwE2fgEJFzIvIhsoADuZIhosi1tVmiIUG7IXOAARjAANBrOAA5sReGdaHlx9IXFMvMZwviimmhc0KjIkE1LCUWWmth04nYIALwZRWgyvZB0XGiWljmg9xOX15BzlMZpAcuMelAcjkKgQCERSJQEABlGB2RBUIQ2ZBkPqgDjQFCwcpbJAqfqDEbQYmVAhkbB6OqgGp1HqNeBoFHQNFUbBffLLJhSTncyBmDY2CgzNB-absO5iebNVofAAsAAY1eNBKAAESIFQ6twAJg1WRyxO2kF2+w82uxuJ1RS56MgOvG+rcF1lRQAdPqsqYYVVg-DoOQMdQuJIAEqQACOTg4mJJk2gMj0k0gbnxhItoFgbQwXCGAEkyaABsMYNTYfg6QyKEzavU2VbaLzFgVBZGY-HE2gxcnRJL2NKvSCfgrlUq2pZ1Zr3DqC5hi2XDaATWqzXmdntUMZtan05m3DqSHQ6G784XV+Xx3Kfcui6WVAGg7X64zmS3UOBWsg+ROFYpDsOh9XFYNhylUA6EmVwPC7IpklSYUXTFcZEMgZDih7cRYwTZwBwsAB+KJbg8dlUJ5L5A0gpBgksABZMhMB9aAyFUBgvlADI1R9ABWb5tRAUApFucjMBwJB1HYzjwBg1BJj2aZfRsURYOwYwAEYyPzNtoA7PMaRJEck1TU5IAAQUkAB5ODJ0wn0JHESwNPNUAROQOh5GgegBC8pobBE0zpXMlZrPEOz4MwqRjCo0VTHGSxcPw-szBiUBahUSASBQSAVByUjzAlaCyHmTCIqiycyunMKmEquC82C0ryoFIoGvguLUTQxLQGSqM8L7Qj0tiLKcrygrSJK0cPCdEVsHGVNsF0mq2gq2zGum-5IB9cQ6FgSxHW6nkXB1aETJmK4dr2g65pdbBvhE+KzC2q7dv2w6ltO86oPYN6bssJbHrAFKho4EbMtUcbDhUWtMiAA)